# Check if a file is opened as Rewrite or Append

Tags: delphi

In Delphi (10.3) is there a way to test if a text file was opened via Rewrite or via Append?
I've found this:
[Checking File is Open in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141302/checking-file-is-open-in-delph)
but it doesn't help as it only says if file is opened for Read or Write.
Note that I can use a global Boolean, initialized to True if I open the file as Append, and to False if Rewrite, but I'm curious to know if the is another way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need to know. In case of `Append` the file pointer is at the end of the file, in case of `Rewrite` it is at 0. In both situations you just write what you need and then close the file, no?

Comment: Didn't you open the file? Or do you want to check how another application opened it?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: it's just out of curiosity ;-)

Comment: @sherlock70: a priori, the file would be open by my own program

Comment: Usually if you need to ask this question, then something is missing in your code. Your code should already know this information. Also, isn't it time to move on from legacy Pascal I/O? And one more thing, I removed some erroneous tags. For instance, the fact that you called a Delphi function named `Rewrite` doesn't mean the question is about url-rewriting. It's important to be careful with tags. If the question is a pure Delphi question then I would tag with the generic delphi tag, and a version specific delphi tag, e.g. delphi-7, delphi-xe8 etc.

Comment: Why on Earth are you still using the antiquated file I/O functions in the modern age? Is it 1970 where you live, and how did you get a time machine to get here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TTextRec(txt).Mode` is `fmOutput` for `Rewrite` and `fmInOut` for `Append` (look in `system.pas`)